# ng-show not updating logout button in the nav bar

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on wiring authentication into my application.  If the user is logged in, I want to display a logout button in the nav bar.

I'm setting $scope.authenticated in my controller, but the logout button doesn't show up all the time.

I've read that I need to use $scope.$apply to tell angular the variable is updated, but when I do that I get this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest

I've worked up a plunker with a demo app showing my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/gCSGIC0gXbfuIjVgp01f?p=preview

App.js

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('salesmanApp', ['ngStorage', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController',
        login: true
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);


app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', 'TokenStorage', function($location, $rootScope, TokenStorage) {

 if (TokenStorage.retrieve() != null) {
  $rootScope.authenticated = true;
 }
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        if (!$rootScope.authenticated && next && !next.login) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
                $location.path('/login');
            });
        }
    });
}]);


app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenAuthInterceptor');
});
```

Controllers.js

```js
var app = angular.module('salesmanApp');

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 'AuthService', '$timeout', function($scope, $location, $rootScope, AuthService, $timeout) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.logout = function() {
     
     AuthService.logout(function() {

        $scope.authenticated = false;
          $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          $location.path('/login');

     });

    };
}]);

app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 'TokenStorage', 'AuthService', '$timeout', function($scope, $location, $rootScope, TokenStorage, AuthService, $timeout) {
    $scope.authenticated = false;

    $scope.login = function() {
    
     var formData = {
       username: $scope.username,
       password: $scope.password
      }
     
     AuthService.login(formData, function(token) {

          $scope.authenticated = true;
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
  
            TokenStorage.store(token);
            $location.path('/home');

            
     }, function() {

       $scope.authenticated = false;
          $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          $scope.error = "Invalid Username or Password"
          TokenStorage.clear();
          
     });


    };
}]);

app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'UserService', function($scope, $http, $location, UserService) {



}]);
```

Services.js

```js
var app = angular.module('salesmanApp');

app.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    
 return {
  getCurrentUserName : function() {
      return $http.get('/api/users/current');
  }
 };
}]);

app.factory('TokenStorage', ['$localStorage', function($localStorage) {
    var storageKey = 'auth_token';
    return {
        store: function(token) {
            return $localStorage.auth_token = token;
        },
        retrieve: function() {
            return $localStorage.auth_token;
        },
        clear: function() {
            delete $localStorage.auth_token;
        }
    };
}]);

app.factory('TokenAuthInterceptor', ['$q', 'TokenStorage', function($q, TokenStorage) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            var authToken = TokenStorage.retrieve();
            if (authToken) {
                config.headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = authToken;
            }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function(error) {
            if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
                TokenStorage.clear();
            }
            return $q.reject(error);
        }
    };
}]);

app.factory('AuthService', ['$http', 'TokenStorage', function($http, TokenStorage) {
 
 return {
  login : function(data, success, error) {
   success("token");
  },
  logout : function(success) {
   TokenStorage.clear();
            success();
  },
  current: function(success, error) {
   success("user");
  }
 };
}]);
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="salesmanApp">

<head>
    <title>Login Demo</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>


</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            
            <span>Login Demo</span>
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="authenticated">
                <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>


</header>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="services.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting rid of the $rootScope.authenticated and $scope.authenticated in favor of calling a new method in AuthService: AuthService.authenticated().

I created a new controller called navController:

```
app.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 'AuthService', '$timeout', function($scope, $location, $rootScope, AuthService, $timeout) {

$scope.authenticated = AuthService.authenticated();
$scope.$watch(AuthService.authenticated, function(newVal, oldVal){
      $scope.authenticated = newVal;
    });
$scope.logout = function() {

    AuthService.logout(function() {
        $scope.authenticated = false;
        $location.path('/login');
    });
};
```

}]);

Added this controller to the header in html:

```
<header ng-controller="navController">
```

$scope.$watch is what I needed to get the logout button to show up when I was authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="salesmanApp">

<head>
    <title>Login Demo</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>


</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            
            <span>Login Demo</span>
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="authenticated">
                <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>


</header>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="services.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```